# Division between Bootstrap accordion elements not displaying

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've copied the examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse&stacked=h) and [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion) to display an accordion using Bootstrap, but the different elements in my accordion won't appear separately from each other.  Here's what my code produces for a two element accordion and what it looks like:

[image: 2 element accordion]

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Here's my html which is just like the two sites I linked above:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div id="reports-accordion">
    <div class='panel panel-default'>

      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Acquisitions</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel body
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Circulation</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel body
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the css and js I'm including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How do I get the division and spacing between elements in my accordion to display correctly?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to modify your structure try this code

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div id="reports-accordion">
        <div class='panel panel-default'>

          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Acquisitions</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel body
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
<div class='panel panel-default'>
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Circulation</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel body
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Even you can try on your existing structure I think you are missing `margin-top` property

```
.panel-heading {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Try adding this code and if possible please share your code in fiddle

Comment: Ah your code did the trick, no need to share in jsfiddle.  I didn't notice that I needed a a div class with panel & panel-default for each element.  Thank you!